# vscode ignores indent settings and goes back to tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some troubles with my vscode settings. I have the following settings:

```
detect indentation: false
insert spaces: True
tab size: 4
```

But anytime I focus out of vscode it will automatically change to tabs as indents for my python code!

I have recorded it and uploaded it to youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ddf3IP8zNY. Here you can see in the bottom right corner that tabs are choosen as indent. I changed them to spaces and go into settings to check that all settings are correct to have spaces as indent but as soon as i close settings it goes back to tabs!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on *Editor: Detect Indentation*

I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Tried with that and wouldnt work neither :/